# Find sentences with describing context using stanford NLP

Tags: machine-learning, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

Is there any way to find those sentences that are describing objects?

For example sentences like "This is a good product" or "You are very beautiful"

I guess I can create an algorithm by using TokenSequencePattern and filter with POS some patterns like PRONUN + VERB + ADJECTIVE but don't think would be something reliable.

I am asking you if there is something out of the box, what I am trying to do is to identify review comments on a webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of POS tagging, you would achieve better results by dependency parsing. By using that instead of POS tagging & patterns as you mentioned, you will have richer and accurate information about the sentence structure.
Example:

https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/?text=The%20product%20was%20really%20very%20good.&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=0&cph=0

[image]

Stanford NLP does support [depedency parsing](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml).
Apart from that you can also use the brilliant [SpaCy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features).

Comment: Thanks!
it does exactly what I need, I will try to play with the dependencies